# Trying to localize plugin on Bedrock stack in Wordpress

Tags: php, localization, wordpress

I'm trying to localize a WordPress plugin at work. I've created the necessary `.mo` and `.po` files and tried stashing them in various places, but I just can't get the localization to work. I noticed that in the Bedrock `application.php` file that it specifies I should place the language files in `app/languages` but it's still not working.

I've tried naming my `.mo` files as `plugin-en.mo` and `en.mo` but no success.

I've set my WPLANG accordingly: `define('WPLANG','en');`.

Do I need to insert a `load_plugin_textdomain()` function? If so, where would I put it?

Comment: Of interest: [How to make a WordPress plugin translation ready?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80334/12615)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A site running Bedrock stores its language files in a different directory: `app/languages`. There's no need to add a textdomain to the `_e()` and `__()` functions wrapped around your strings.

So adding all `.mo` and `.po` files to the `app/languages` folder does the trick. Ex: `_e( 'String-to-be-translated')` and `__('String to be translated')`

Check out [this link](https://github.com/roots/bedrock/issues/30) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If your plugin is called `myplugin`, your language files should be (eg) `myplugin-fr_FR.mo` and `myplugin-fr_FR.mo` (for french).  The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language) says the convention's to have both language code and country code - I don't know if only having `en` (not, say, `en_US`) is contributing to your problem.

Put them in a subdirectory called `languages`, and load them with something like

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );
function myplugin_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' ); 
}
```

in your main plugin file (if you load them from a file in a different directory, you'll need to modify the third parameter).

Comment: I've done all that and followed the guides numerous times. I guess what I need to know is where my main plugin file would be if I'm using the Bedrock stack (Installing with Composer)? The file structure is different than a typical WordPress site.